# Simple or regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a number of strings from my log file which I want to filter by regexp:

```
Oct 21 08:05:27 ph10001019 phs: got valid password for flat 200
Oct 21 08:07:34 ph10001014 phs: got valid password for flat 200
Oct 21 08:08:05 ph10001014 phs: got valid password for flat 200
Oct 21 08:19:25 ph10001019 phs: got valid password for flat 200: 1234
Oct 21 08:22:13 ph10001019 phs: got valid password for flat 200: 1234
Oct 21 08:24:12 ph10001019 phs: got valid password for flat 200: 1234
Oct 21 08:26:41 ph10001014 phs: got valid password for flat 200: 0034
```

This regexp returns string I need:

```
phs:\sgot\svalid\spassword.*200:\s0034
```

That's fine but I have two variants of last number. I tried folowing regexp but it returns empty string.

```
phs:\sgot\svalid\spassword.*200:\s(0034)|(4321)
```

What's wrong with second regexp?

Comment: Added input example.

Comment: did you want to match all the above strings?

Comment: Nope I want to match strings with 0034 and 4321 numbers in the end of string.

Comment: it doesn't return an *empty string*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to match only the last string. Avoid using `\s` for matching whitespace because `\s` would match newline characters also.

```
phs:\h+got\h+valid\h+password.*?200:\h+(?:0034|4321)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/13)

```
$data = <<< EOT
Oct 21 08:05:27 ph10001019 phs: got valid password for flat 200
Oct 21 08:07:34 ph10001014 phs: got valid password for flat 200
Oct 21 08:08:05 ph10001014 phs: got valid password for flat 200
Oct 21 08:19:25 ph10001019 phs: got valid password for flat 200: 1234
Oct 21 08:22:13 ph10001019 phs: got valid password for flat 200: 1234
Oct 21 08:24:12 ph10001019 phs: got valid password for flat 200: 1234
Oct 21 08:26:41 ph10001014 phs: got valid password for flat 200: 0034
EOT;
preg_match_all('~phs:\h+got\h+valid\h+password.*?200:\h+(?:0034|4321)~', $data, $match);
print_r($match);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => phs: got valid password for flat 200: 0034
        )

)
```

Comment: You understand me right. Stange but your regex dones'nt show results in my secure crt command string. Searching for mistake.

Comment: wait, i will show you the result through preg_match_all function.

Answer (score 1):

```
phs:\sgot\svalid\spassword.*200(?::\s(?:0034|1234))?
```

Try this. This should give you your result.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rQ6mK9/12